# Newb AS3 error: 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Tween

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I seem to have a problem here with my AS3 code.

Im just trying out AS3 for pratically the first time and I keep runing into errors. Usually I tinker about and seem to resolve them, but this one stumps me, since it "should" work. Can anyone help me out please?

```
package {
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import mx.transitions.Tween;
import mx.transitions.easing.*;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class InfoModule extends MovieClip
{
    function InfoModule()
    {
        trace("InfoModule Added.");
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, GetData);
        addEventListener(Event.CLICK, InfoTweenIn);
        //addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, InfoTweenOut);
    }

    public function GetData(event):void
    {
        //future php code here
    }

    private function InfoTweenIn(Event:MouseEvent){
        var TweenIn:Tween = new Tween (this,"_y",Regular.easeInOut,this.y,400,1,true);
    }


    private function destroyMe(object:*):void {
        if(object.parent != null){
            var parent:DisplayObjectContainer = object.parent;
            parent.removeChild(object);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Sooo, I keep getting an error on the Tween class, line 34 saying:

1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Tween.
and

1180: Call to a possibly undefined method Tween.

and a few more. If you need the full error list, please tell me.

Anyway, I'm pretty sure I imported the Tween library, so what's up?

Please help and thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Flash Professional IDE? The [Tween](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/transitions/Tween.html) class is in the fl.* package these days:

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
```

Comment: Well that was dumb of me. Sometimes the correct answer is the simplest one I guess. Since I was searching online for answers before coming to you guys, I just copy+pasted a lot of snippets and ended up like that.

thank you, it works now :)

Comment: Happens all the time. Vote the answer up if it was helpful, Marco.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up snippets from Actionscript 2.0 and Actionscript 3.0 which is why the compiler cannot find the Tween classes. I recommend you don't use mx.transitions.Tween which is AS2. Stick to Actionscript 3.0 and use an easy to use third party tween engine such as  TweenLite or Tweener. Both have example pages to get you started:

http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/

http://code.google.com/p/tweener/

Comment: I might move to Caurina tweener, since I have some experience with it, but since this is a farly simple program, without many tweens, I just wanted to get it to work simply. I am also new to AS3, so I dont wanna bring too many stuff in just now.

Thanks :)

Comment: Tweener is easier to use and more robust than the built in classes. With the old mx.transitions.* I remember there were dereferencing issues where if you didn't watch it your reference would be weak by default and get swallowed up by garbage collection before the Tween ended. That is why I usually recommend using one of the Tweening engines.